# ASP.NET Core TypeLoadException Could not load type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web'

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the course of developing an ASP.NET Core MVC project, I have run into this exception multiple times.

It happens when POSTing back to an MVC controller. Let's say the ViewModel looks like this:

```
using System.Web;

namespace MyNamespace 
{
    public class MyViewModel 
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> MyOptions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the header for this view contains this

```
@model MyNamespace.MyViewModel
```

As mentioned, on POST back (assuming the View has a form and a postback in it) this exception is thrown.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>       TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>       System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, int typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, int typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, int methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)

Comment: `System.Web` => `ASP.NET`; `Microsoft.AspNetCore` => `ASP.NET Core`. **DON'T** mix them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple hours of debugging, the solution turned out to be an incorrect using statement.

`SelectListItem` exists in both `System.Web` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering`

However, .NET Core does not support some element of this when referenced from `System.Web`

Simply changing the using statement to the following fixes the issue:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
```

This is likely to occur with other types, so if you're getting strange errors in ASP.NET Core MVC, it may be a good idea to check your using statements for `System.Web`.