# Build error when upgrading WPF application to .NET 7

Tags: .net, wpf, upgrade, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to upgrade a WPF application from .NET 4.6.1 to .NET 7. After working out the initial issues, I'm left with a single build error.

```
MC1000  Unknown build error, 'Could not find type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' in assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\7.0.5\ref\net7.0\System.Web.dll'.'
```

I have no idea where to start looking to fix this one. Does somebody know how to fix this? Or any idea where I can start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891928/asp-net-core-typeloadexception-could-not-load-type-system-web-preapplicationsta

Comment: Do you use/reference `System.Web.dll` somewhere in your application?

Comment: @mm8 I have removed all references to System.Web but I still get the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed the issue by uninstalling/installing some nuget packages. Maybe some of them still had old references to the System.Web namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you encountered is expected.

The System.Web.dll from '.net framwork' really has class:

[PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute?view=netframework-4.8.1)

But in .NET 7, it was been removed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web?view=net-7.0

So all the code that related to this need to be recheck, all of the code related to this need to be rewrite. Please check which side you used the PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute.